# Unable to bring uploaded images into uploads file using php

Tags: php, html

After creating a form and typing the php code, i have a form where i am able to input a file, specifically an image, and without reciving any error messages, as well as getting the success message in my url, the image uploaded still can not be found in its destination folder.

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Art Here">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </form>
```

and here's the php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $file['size'];
$fileError = $file['error'];
$fileType = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allow = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allow)) {
    if($fileError === 0){
        if($fileSize < 5000000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = 'uplaods/'.$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
            header("Location: index.php?uploadsucess");
        } else{
            echo "Your file is too big";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uplaoding your file!";
    }
} else{
    echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
}
```

}

Code is based and modified from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaRq73y5MJk

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just check your html element I think you missed something

Comment: which folder you are uploading - uplaods or uploads . Is it typo or you are doing it intentionally ?

Answer (score 1):

in your form add this

```
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

example

```
  <form method="post" class="login-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
     action="my.php">
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag.
2) `fileDestination = 'uplaods/'.$fileNameNew;`spelling mistake on file name. (If it is intentional, then my bad).
3) `<input type='file'>` type should be file.

Answer (score 0):

how did you communicate with `$_FILES`? You need to use 
`type="file"` in your input

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"` to your `form`-tag:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If it then still doesn't work, check the `upload_max_filesize` and the `post_max_size` settings in your `php.ini`. If your file is too big, only `move_uploaded_file()` will return `false`, so check that function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` misses an **attribute** to send files:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

And to be sure the upload is done, put the `move_uploaded_file()` in a condition because the function returns a **boolean** :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination)) {
    header("Location: index.php?uploadsucess");
} else {
    header("Location: index.php?uploadfail");
}
```

Also, a better way to get your **file extension** is using `pathinfo()` :

```
pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

- you don't have any `<input type="file">` in your form
- you maybe mispelled your upload directory : *uplaods*

[php.net - move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
[php.net - pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: i made all of these changes and fixed it up and yet still im unable to upload to the 'upload' folder. Here's the new code: https://pastebin.com/8U05xXfm thanks for taking a look

Comment: @nickwiseman you haven't changed everything: the way you get the file extension, and the most important: put the `move_uploaded_file()` into a condition to know if it worked ! What's the output with a correct file ? Maybe try to add [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) before the upload path, like: `$fileDestination = __DIR__ .  '/beta/vangogh/upload/'.$fileNameNew;` ?